# Postgresql using json_build_obj

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to get a column of `geometries` from a table with `PostgreSQL` and `PostGIS`

```
SELECT json_build_object(
           'type', 'FeatureCollection',
           'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json) 
        ) FROM (SELECT position FROM permit) as t
```

This returns an `Array` with a key `json_build_object`.

```
[
 {
  "json_build_object": {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -97.74318277,
      30.25239259
     ]
   },
   "properties": {}
   }
  ]
 }
 }
]
```

I would like a single `FeatureCollection` object.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -97.74318277,
      30.25239259
     ]
   },
   "properties": {}
   }
  ]
 }
```

Is this the expected output of the query? And how can I get a clean `FeatureCollection` otherwise?

Comment: Hi there, which postgres version are you using?

Comment: @JimJones It's Postgres version 12

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. Check this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7c6c7336c16935ad184bb04d49b9283b
Can you run this code in your postgres and tell me what you got?